# MSDeploy override contentPath directory with manifest

Tags: replace, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to override the installation directory when using contentPath provider with an MSDeploy package that contains a manifest.

I'm sure I've done this in the past, but just can't get it to work.

What am I missing?

**Manifest used to create package:**

```
<siteManifest>
  <contentPath path="C:\packages" />
  <runCommand path="do something here" />
</siteManifest>
```

**Command to install package:**

This is straight from documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
         -source:package=deploy.zip 
         -dest:auto 
         -replace:objectName=contentPath,
                  targetAttributeName=path,
                  replace=C:\otherPath
```

**Update**

Discovered this works for files, but still no joy for directories.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
         -source:package=deploy.zip 
         -dest:auto 
         -replace:objectName=filePath,
                  targetAttributeName=path,
                  match=somefile\.txt
                  replace=newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to specify a manifest as the destination, add a contentPath provider and set the path to the override location. Surprisingly this works when source package also contains a manifest with contentPath provider.

destination.xml

```
<siteManifest>
   <contentPath path="C:\OverrideLocation" />
</siteManifest>
```

Command:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
     -source:package=deploy.zip 
     -dest:destination.xml
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `<sitemanifest/>` instead of `<siteManifest/>` and `-dest:manifest=destination.xml`?